# How to add a mask on image without use absolute element

Tags: css

I want to add a mask with the color #000000 and 20% opacity on image

usually, code like this

```
img {
  position: relative;
}
img::after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  position: absolute;
}
```

Is there a css property to achieve the same effect; i have tried the filter attribute and mask-image, but it doesn't work;
thank you;

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Also images cannot have pseudo-elements. Use the wrapper of the image instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter: brightness` or create an overlay `div` with gray background + position absolute to put mask on image.

```css
img {
  filter: brightness(30%);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" />
```

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: @Rob far as I known void elements can have a slash at the end both are valid as HTML5

Comment: Yes, this is true, but the slash is not specified anywhere as being needed, it carries no meaning, it does nothing and browsers are instructed to ignore it. It has no value and is pointless. So why would one put it there? We never did in the past. It's a relatively recent, strange phenomena.